# Where to mention executable file in appspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, discord, discord.py

I am trying to deploy and run a simple python application (discord bot) on AWC EC2 through github.
I have setup CodeDeploy and CodePipeline

1. Do I need the CodeBuild?
2. Where do I mention my main.py executable in appspec.yml to run the code?
3. What all hooks(BeforeInstall, AfterInstall, ApplicationStart, ApplicationStop) are important in appspec.yml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need the CodeBuild?

Depends on your application. For some it may be required, for others may not.

> Where do I mention my main.py executable in appspec.yml to run the code?

`appspec.yml` just runs commands in the instance shell. So you execute your `main.py` as you would normally run it manually on the instance, e.g.

```
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/RynMyPyton.sh
```

where `scripts/RynMyPyton.sh` would be

```
#!bin/bash

python main.py
```

> What all hooks(BeforeInstall, AfterInstall, ApplicationStart, ApplicationStop) are important in appspec.yml file?

They are explained in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#appspec-hooks-server).